# Converting string to ascii using ord()

Tags: python

I must preface this by saying that I am a neophyte (learning), so please waive the omission of the obvious in deference to a man who has had limited exposure to your world (Python).

My objective is to get string from a user and convert it to Hex and Ascii string. I was able to accomplish this successfully with hex (`encode("hex")`), but not so with ascii. I found the `ord()` method and attempted to use that, and if I just use: `print ord(i)`, the loop iterates the through and prints the values to the screen vertically, not where I want them. So, I attempted to capture them with a string array so I can concat them to a line of string, printing them horizontally under the 'Hex" value. I've just about exhausted my resources on figuring this out ... any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
while True:
   stringName = raw_input("Convert string to hex & ascii(type stop to quit): ")
   if stringName == 'stop':
      break
   else:   
      convertedVal = stringName.encode("hex")
      new_list = []
      convertedVal.strip() #converts string into char
      for i in convertedVal:
         new_list = ord(i)


      print "Hex value: " + convertedVal
      print "Ascii value: " + new_list
```

Comment: What are you expecting your ASCII output to look like? Just comma-delimited decimal values? i.e.: "97, 98, 65, 65"

Comment: if a user enters the string: '123431': hex= 313233343331 ascii = 49 50 51 52 51 49

Comment: Thanks DP .... Also, I didn't mean to put spaces between the ascii values on my last comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
while True:
   stringName = raw_input("Convert string to hex & ascii(type stop to quit): ").strip()
   if stringName == 'stop':
      break

   print "Hex value: ", stringName.encode('hex')
   print "ASCII value: ", ', '.join(str(ord(c)) for c in stringName)
```

Comment: Yes! I had code almost identical to that earlier, but switched up! Why did you use the .strip() on the stringName ... line? Again, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
def convert_to_ascii(text):
    return " ".join(str(ord(char)) for char in text)
```

This gives you

```
>>> convert_to_ascii("hello")
'104 101 108 108 111'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print "ASCII value: ",  ", ".join(str(i) for i in new_list)
```